# Can't scroll items in a div with overflow auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, astrojs

This container is suppose to scroll horizontally since I have `overflow-x-auto` and that all the buttons overflows when I am on a 1024px screen width but that's not the case.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div
      class="hidden lg:flex items-center gap-x-2 overflow-x-auto bg-green-500 p-2 w-full h-full"
    >
      <FilterByDomainBtn
        text="Tous"
        className="w-[144px] bg-crina-primary text-white font-gilroy-bold all-projects"
      />
      <FilterByDomainBtn text="Ecologie" className="ecology" />
      <FilterByDomainBtn text="Evènementiel" className="events" />
      <FilterByDomainBtn text="Finance" className="finance" />
      <FilterByDomainBtn text="Immobilier" className="estate" />
      <FilterByDomainBtn text="High-Tech" className="highTech" />
    </div>
```

I tried disactivating my JavaScript thinking it's some js code listening to click on the button that is blocking the scroll but that's not the case.

Comment: Your container is a `flex` container, so presumably your items are still allowed to _shrink_ so that they all fit into the container.

Comment: The container is also `hidden`, so it doesn't display. Please [edit] your question so that it demonstrates the issue (see [mre] for more).

Answer (score 1):

When I try to reproduce this snippet with HTML and CSS, it works.

I'd guess you should use `className` instead of `class` because you seem to be programming in JSX there.

Comment: This is perhaps more of a comment than an answer as it stand snow.  You might enhance with a functional snippet using the guidance on how to do so with JSX on the meta site here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support

Comment: the snippet is from an Astro js project and `className` there is a props for adding new classes to the component.

Comment: MarkSchultheiss You're right sorry, I couldn't comment due to my lack of reputation points.

@davdev Alright, have you checked your content does exceed your container's width ? Maybe if you could provide minimal infos about your children components we could be more helpful.